# Automake LibSocketCan

Tags: makefile, automake, socketcan

I am using automake to build my project. My project uses pthread and libsocketcan. I have installed libsocketcan with the command

```
sudo apt-get install libsocketcan-dev
```

In eclpise I have added linker flags for pthread and libsocketcan. The code will compile and run. When I run my automake script the build fails with the error.

```
gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-socketcan’[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

My makefile.am is as follows:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign subdir-objects

bin_PROGRAMS = MAIN_Application

LDFLAGS = \
    -pthread \
    -socketcan


AM_CPPFLAGS = \
    -I$(srcdir)/include \
    -I$(srcdir)/include/utilities \
    -I$(srcdir)/include/comms

MAIN_Application_SOURCES = \
    src/main.c \
    src/scheduler.c \
    src/utilities/time_conversions.c \
    src/utilities/ring_buffer.c \
    src/utilities/logger.c \
    src/comms/can.c
```

If I remove all code and references here to `socketcan`, everything works fine. I get a nice application binary that can run threads. Once I add can I can no longer build. I have tried with the `LDFLAGS` `socketcan`, `libsocketcan` and `libsocketcan-dev`.

What `LDFLAG` do I need in my makefile to properly include `libsocketcan`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need any "`LDFLAG`" for this. `LDFLAGS` is for linker flags, not for adding libraries to link to.

You can have `MAIN_Application` link against libsocketcan with something like:

```
MAIN_Application_LDADD = -lsocketcan
```